# vb.NET application using AccessDB to run MAKETABLE query wont work on other machine. errors dont make sense. Possibly Access version difference issue?

Tags: vb.net

I know my heading doensn't make much sense, but I'm quite lost as to what is happening!

I have the following code:

```
Sub UpdateStatusReport()

    Try
        Dim oAccess As Access.Application
        oAccess = New Access.Application()

        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("I:\GPS_Conversion\XY_Convert2.mdb", True)
        oAccess.DoCmd.SetWarnings(WarningsOn:=False)
        oAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery("A1qryMt_FindMaxStatusReportID")
        oAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery("A2qryUpd_ReduceMaxStatusReportID")
        oAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery("A3qryMt_StatusReport")
        oAccess.DoCmd.SetWarnings(WarningsOn:=True)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oAccess)
        oAccess = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine("updated table with live info")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ex1 = ex.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\logfile.txt", ex1, True)

    End Try

End Sub
```

I import the following:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.DataRowExtensions
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports ADODB
```

The error I get from the above is:

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A09C5): The OpenQuery action was canceled.
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.DoCmd.OpenQuery(Object QueryName, AcView View, AcOpenDataMode DataMode)
       at CurrentPositionHTMLCreate.Module1.UpdateStatusReport() in C:\IT3_New\Michael\CurrentPositionHTMLCreate\CurrentPositionHTMLCreate\Module1.vb:line 30
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A09C5): The OpenQuery action was canceled.
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.DoCmd.OpenQuery(Object QueryName, AcView View, AcOpenDataMode DataMode)
       at CurrentPositionHTMLCreate.Module1.UpdateStatusReport() in C:\IT3_New\Michael\CurrentPositionHTMLCreate\CurrentPositionHTMLCreate\Module1.vb:line 30
```

this is line 30:

```
 oAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery("A1qryMt_FindMaxStatusReportID")
```

Its a small sub that calls a series of MAKETABLE queries in access.

On the computer that i wrote the program on it works fine, but when i use any other computer i get all sorts of issues. Ive narrowed it down by slowly breaking apart the code until i found what didn't work, from the whole application.

basically this updates a table in the DB from a DBO that is on a slq server. I cant get direct access to that server, i can only access it via the accessDB with these queries in it.

basically, ive come to the conclusion that its a version issue? it looks like i have office 2007 on this machine, and most other machines ive tried it on has 2000 or 2003. but i installed "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" on those machines thinking that it might be the issue, but it hasnt resolved my problem.

is there another way i can do this? is there some backward compatible code i can write that might make it workable in older versions of access? Im not really sure what im looking for here, but i need a way to be able to get the live data from the DBO's and update it into the database that i use for this application.

---

**UPDATE*********

---

So after much work on trying to solve this issue, i was unable to do so, i eventually moved the updates into an access form and have the DB running in the background on a machine in the network that is used as a clock.

it would seem that there are version clashes happening somewhere, but i just cant seem to work out where.

Comment: Do you have any exception handling? If so, you'd probably receive a meaningful error message, instead of having to resort to the cryptic event log entries. Also, at what point does it fail? You've not posted any indication of where the failure is happening. Your small bit of included code contains a hard-coded path reference to a folder on an `I:` drive - does that drive and directory exist on the other machine? Is the database file in that directory? You've omitted a bunch of info that might help us help you solve this issue.

Comment: ok, ill try and answer your questions as best as i can. i havent put any exceptions handling in yet, but im in the process of putting some in now. it seems to fail at the first line, "Dim oAccess As Access.Application" but i will confirm that. 'I:' is a network drive, which is where the accessDB is stored. i know that it works fine, because i can access it with the rest of the application.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional info there instead of in comments, where people can see it when reading your question. It will improve your chances of getting help. You can also properly format it so it's readable there, where that's difficult to do in comments. :-)

Comment: ive updated with more meaningful errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the database is not getting opened because the connection string is incorrect on the different computers. For example, the file `I:\GPS_Conversion\XY_Convert2.mdb` might be mapped to drive q: or not at all. After the open statement, check the status to see if the database is really open. It may not generate an error if it fails to open.

Comment: I checked to see if the DB is opening, and it seems that everything is fine. all computers within the network have the same mappings on all drives, besides their home drives. It is quite confusing :S

Comment: Ive isolated the connection, and it would seem that it is opening the db. I also connect to the db in another section of the code with no issue, it just seems to not work when i connect to a make table.